# Arquivo está sendo enviado para fora da pasta definida com o método move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Olá, estou fazendo um sisteminha onde eu previamente crio uma pasta, e posteriormente faço o upload do arquivo (mais para frente vou tratar se é imagem ou vídeo), o problema é que o método `move_uploaded_file` está ignorando as variáveis após a primeira barra e fazendo o upload na primeira pasta, não na pasta definida pelo usuário:

```php
$nome_pasta = $_POST['pasta']; //É o nome da pasta que o usuário criou na tela anterior do meu sistema.

if (isset($_POST['pasta'])){
    try{
        mkdir('./public/'. $nome_pasta) or die("erro ao criar diretório"); // Cria uma nova pasta dentro do diretório atual
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo 'Exceção capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }   
    }
foreach ($_FILES["files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "public/$nome_pasta/$name" );
    }
}
```

[image: Print do problema]

Tentei contra barra mas não rolou sentimento também... alguma ideia?

Comment: Se tentares mesmo: `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "public/Teste/$name" );` ele faz o suposto?

Comment: O man que confundi na resposta...

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` para te retornar o diretório raiz sob onde o script atual é executado.

`move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "./public/$nome_pasta/$name" );`

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54630/discussion-on-answer-by-magichat-arquivo-esta-sendo-enviado-para-fora-da-pasta-d)